# python regex to match whole line with a particular regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with a list of regex patterns and string containing '\n's' i.e a string with seperate lines ... I need a generic regex that can match the whole line with patterns in the regex file such that i can do something like

re.compile(r'generic_regex%s') %regex_pattern from file and it automatically matches the whole line much like grep.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you mean you want to match the entire string containing the newlines (\n), or just match the text between newlines? i.e., search in MULTILINE mode, or search each 'line' individually in the input string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(^.*?%s.*?$)" %expression, text, re.MULTILINE)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust for any boundaries etc...

```
import re
import mmap

def find_re(fname, rx): # rx is a compiled re object
    with open(fname) as fin:
        mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        return rx.findall(mm)
```

Shoud be fast for just sequential access... re-work the regex if needs be to go over multiple lines...